# GLEW build fail

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, makefile, xlib, glew

I need to load extensions in Ubuntu 11.10.  I tried building GLEW but I get the following odd error...

```
~/Downloads/glew-1.7.0$ make 
cc -shared -Wl,-soname=libGLEW.so.1.7 -o lib/libGLEW.so.1.7.0 src/glew.pic_o -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lXmu -lXi -lGLU -lGL -lXext -lX11 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
make: *** [lib/libGLEW.so.1.7.0] Error 1
```

Here's what I've found suggested (and thus tried with no success):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mesa-common-dev

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libx11-dev
```

I also saw somewhere to simply put a `#define GL_GLEXT_EXTENSIONS` at the top of the file, and that didn't work either.

If anyone could show me how to fix that odd error so I could build GLEW and/or show me how to manually load OpenGL extensions in Linux (I only see code on how to do it in Windows...) that would be great!

Comment: Are you sure this is an SO question?  Looks more like you're trying to configure your system and might be better off trying [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Apparently you are on a Ubuntu'esque system. You should consider installing GLEW through the package manager.

Comment: There may be some overlap between SO and AskUbuntu, but this is clearly a programming-related question that should be appropriate for SO.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xmu is the X Miscellaneous Utilities Library and
Xi is the X Input Device Extension Library

You need to install them first:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev
sudo apt-get install libxi-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear why you are building the GLEW library when you could just install it like so...

```
sudo apt-get install libglew1.6-dev
```

Comment: GLEW 1.7 doesn't appear in packages yet.

Comment: @StevenLu: That is a reasonable explanation, except that the OP didn't indicate that 1.6 would not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be a combination of problems.

Personally I think you need to configure before you actually make the library.

The sequence is always:

- ./configure

  - make
  - sudo make install

(you can combine the 3rd command with the 2nd but I always prefer to split the 2).

P.S. if you prefer to do everything as super user do:

1   sudo su 
2   ./configure
3   make
4   make install